# Understanding Move Capture in Lambdas for C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, move, rvalue-reference

I have a question regarding the workaround proposed in order to address move capture in C++11 lambdas. In particular, taking the example from [Meyer's book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do):

```
std::vector<double> data;
... 
auto func = std::bind( [](const std::vector<double>& data) 
                       { /*uses of data*/ },
                       std::move(data)
                     );
```

My question is: what would be the consequences/meaning of declaring the parameter "data" as an rvalue reference?:

```
auto func = std::bind( [](std::vector<double>&& data)
...
```

To help you guide the answer, I'll make three claims. Please tell me if I'm right or wrong:

- In both cases, the move capture semantics included in C++14 are well emulated.
- In both cases, it is not safe to use data after the definition of "func".
- The difference is that in the second case (rvalue reference), we are stating that the callable object (the lambda) could move the contents of "data".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the consequences are that it won't compile! If you still pass `std::move(data)` to `bind`,then `bind` will move-construct an internal `std::vector<double>`, and will attempt to pass it ( a non temporary!) to the lambda taking an rvalue-ref.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what would be the consequences/meaning of declaring the parameter
>   "`data`" as an rvalue reference?

It won't compile (at least if you attempt to actually call `func`). `std::bind` always pass bound arguments as lvalues, which won't bind to the rvalue reference.

> In both cases, it is not safe to use data after the definition of "func".

`data` is left in a valid but unspecified state by the move. You can use it the same way you use a vector whose contents are unknown.

Comment: always beating me to it @T.C. !

Comment: A non-const lvalue reference works, though, and can be used as source of a move construction or move assignment. Of course on a subsequent invocation of the lambda, the old contents would in all likelihood be gone (with all likelihood meaning indeed 100% probability for any of the major implementations, as they all leave the source vector empty).

Comment: I was assuming that std::bind had an overloaded version with rvalue references for its parameters. I should have tried compiling before asking. Silly of me! Thanks to all for the clarifications.